# Combining code for two sensors in one programming

Tags: arduino-uno

We need to read two readings of Humidity and Temperature from 2 different locations. We can run each of them separately but we don't know how we can make them work simultaneously in one program. We are using a TH02 sensor that we connect to I2C and DHT11 that is connected to one of the Analog port.

We are connecting them to Grove base shield V2, which is on top of Arduino uno wifi.

TH02 Code:

```
 void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);        // start serial for output

Serial.println("****TH02_dev demo by seeed studio****\n");
/* Power up,delay 150ms,until voltage is stable */
delay(150);
/* Reset HP20x_dev */
TH02.begin();
delay(100);

/* Determine TH02_dev is available or not */
Serial.println("TH02_dev is available.\n");
}


void loop()
{
float temper = TH02.ReadTemperature();
Serial.println("Temperature: ");
Serial.print(temper);
Serial.println("C\r\n");

float humidity = TH02.ReadHumidity();
Serial.println("Humidity: ");
Serial.print(humidity);
Serial.println("%\r\n");
delay(1000); 
}
```

DHT11 Code:

```
byte read_dht11_dat()
{
byte i = 0;
byte result=0;
for(i=0; i< 8; i++){

    while(!(PINC & _BV(DHT11_PIN)));  // wait for 50us
    delayMicroseconds(30);

    if(PINC & _BV(DHT11_PIN))
    result |=(1<<(7-i));
    while((PINC & _BV(DHT11_PIN)));  // wait '1' finish
}
return result;
}

void setup()
{
DDRC |= _BV(DHT11_PIN);
PORTC |= _BV(DHT11_PIN);

Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("Ready");
}

void loop()
{
byte dht11_dat[5];
byte dht11_in;
byte i;
// start condition
// 1. pull-down i/o pin from 18ms
PORTC &= ~_BV(DHT11_PIN);
delay(18);
PORTC |= _BV(DHT11_PIN);
delayMicroseconds(40);

DDRC &= ~_BV(DHT11_PIN);
delayMicroseconds(40);

dht11_in = PINC & _BV(DHT11_PIN);

if(dht11_in){
    Serial.println("dht11 start condition 1 not met");
    return;
}
delayMicroseconds(80);

dht11_in = PINC & _BV(DHT11_PIN);

if(!dht11_in){
    Serial.println("dht11 start condition 2 not met");
    return;
}
delayMicroseconds(80);
// now ready for data reception
for (i=0; i<5; i++)
dht11_dat[i] = read_dht11_dat();

DDRC |= _BV(DHT11_PIN);
PORTC |= _BV(DHT11_PIN);

byte dht11_check_sum = dht11_dat[0]+dht11_dat[1]+dht11_dat[2]+dht11_dat[3];
// check check_sum
if(dht11_dat[4]!= dht11_check_sum)
{
    Serial.println("DHT11 checksum error");
}

Serial.print("Current humdity = ");
Serial.print(dht11_dat[0], DEC);
Serial.print(".");
Serial.print(dht11_dat[1], DEC);
Serial.print("%  ");
Serial.print("temperature = ");
Serial.print(dht11_dat[2], DEC);
Serial.print(".");
Serial.print(dht11_dat[3], DEC);
Serial.println("C  ");

delay(2000);
}
```

Comment: We are new to arduino and we are trying to understand the codes and how the functions work.. It will be a great help if someone makes us understand what we are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This example combines both codes but uses a single `delay`. If you want readings at two different times you should use two `unsigned long` global variables to store the `millis()` of the last time the functions were called. Then you use an `if` statement to only call `readTH02()` or `readDHT11()` when the last `millis` is less than the `<= current-interval`.

It is better to use `millis` interval checking instead of delays but I have not made significant changes to your code to implement that. Take a look at the Arduino IDE example called `BlinkWithoutDelay` to understand how to use intervals instead of `delay()`

```
void setup()
{
  setupTH02();
  setupDHT11();
}

void loop()
{
  readTH02();
  readDHT11();

  delay(1000);
}


void setupTH02()
{
Serial.begin(9600);        // start serial for output

Serial.println("****TH02_dev demo by seeed studio****\n");
/* Power up,delay 150ms,until voltage is stable */
delay(150);
/* Reset HP20x_dev */
TH02.begin();
delay(100);

/* Determine TH02_dev is available or not */
Serial.println("TH02_dev is available.\n");
}


void readTH02()
{
float temper = TH02.ReadTemperature();
Serial.println("Temperature: ");
Serial.print(temper);
Serial.println("C\r\n");

float humidity = TH02.ReadHumidity();
Serial.println("Humidity: ");
Serial.print(humidity);
Serial.println("%\r\n");
//delay(1000); 
}



byte read_dht11_dat()
{
byte i = 0;
byte result=0;
for(i=0; i< 8; i++){

    while(!(PINC & _BV(DHT11_PIN)));  // wait for 50us
    delayMicroseconds(30);

    if(PINC & _BV(DHT11_PIN))
    result |=(1<<(7-i));
    while((PINC & _BV(DHT11_PIN)));  // wait '1' finish
}
return result;
}

void setupDHT11()
{
DDRC |= _BV(DHT11_PIN);
PORTC |= _BV(DHT11_PIN);

Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("Ready");
}

void readDHT11()
{
byte dht11_dat[5];
byte dht11_in;
byte i;
// start condition
// 1. pull-down i/o pin from 18ms
PORTC &= ~_BV(DHT11_PIN);
delay(18);
PORTC |= _BV(DHT11_PIN);
delayMicroseconds(40);

DDRC &= ~_BV(DHT11_PIN);
delayMicroseconds(40);

dht11_in = PINC & _BV(DHT11_PIN);

if(dht11_in){
    Serial.println("dht11 start condition 1 not met");
    return;
}
delayMicroseconds(80);

dht11_in = PINC & _BV(DHT11_PIN);

if(!dht11_in){
    Serial.println("dht11 start condition 2 not met");
    return;
}
delayMicroseconds(80);
// now ready for data reception
for (i=0; i<5; i++)
dht11_dat[i] = read_dht11_dat();

DDRC |= _BV(DHT11_PIN);
PORTC |= _BV(DHT11_PIN);

byte dht11_check_sum = dht11_dat[0]+dht11_dat[1]+dht11_dat[2]+dht11_dat[3];
// check check_sum
if(dht11_dat[4]!= dht11_check_sum)
{
    Serial.println("DHT11 checksum error");
}

Serial.print("Current humdity = ");
Serial.print(dht11_dat[0], DEC);
Serial.print(".");
Serial.print(dht11_dat[1], DEC);
Serial.print("%  ");
Serial.print("temperature = ");
Serial.print(dht11_dat[2], DEC);
Serial.print(".");
Serial.print(dht11_dat[3], DEC);
Serial.println("C  ");

//delay(2000);
}
```